# Timer query for pause and cancel

Tags: java, android

I am working on timer count but don't know how can I pause Stopwatch nd cancel Stopwatch

```
 package com.ak.gymtimer; 
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.annotation.TargetApi;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.CountDownTimer;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 public class CountDown extends AppCompatActivity {
 long prepTimeInMillis,workTimeInMillis,restTimeInMillis,coolDownTimeInMillis,totalTimeInMillis; 
int round,roundCount=0;
 TextView typeV,roundV,totalTimeV,typeSet; 
CounterClass timer; 
CounterClass1 timer1;
 long pausemillis,pauseTotalMillis;
 int pauseMethodNum;
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_count_down);
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar); typeV =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDownTime);
 roundV =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
 totalTimeV =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTimeleft);
 typeSet =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
 Button pauseBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
 Button cancelBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
 Button nextBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
 Button startBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start); 
prepTimeInMillis = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("prep");
 workTimeInMillis = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("work"); 
restTimeInMillis = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("rest"); coolDownTimeInMillis=getIntent().getExtras().getLong("cooldown");
 round = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("round"); totalTimeInMillis=getIntent().getExtras().getLong("total"); System.out.println("Time in Millis");
 System.out.println(prepTimeInMillis);
 System.out.println(workTimeInMillis);
 System.out.println(restTimeInMillis); System.out.println(coolDownTimeInMillis); 
System.out.println(round);
 System.out.println(totalTimeInMillis);
 if (round == 0){ 
round = 1;
 } 

roundV.setText("1/" + round);
 timer1 = new CounterClass1(totalTimeInMillis,1000);
 timer1.start(); preptimeFunc(); pauseBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
timer.cancel();
 timer1.cancel(); 
} });
 cancelBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override public void onClick(View v) {
 timer1.cancel();
 timer.cancel(); } 
});
 nextBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override public void onClick(View v) {
 timer.start(); timer1.start(); } });
 startBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { timer = new CounterClass(prepTimeInMillis,pausemillis,pauseMethodNum); timer.start(); timer1 = new CounterClass1(prepTimeInMillis,pauseTotalMillis); timer1.start(); } }); } public void preptimeFunc(){ typeSet.setText("Count Down"); timer = new CounterClass(prepTimeInMillis,1000,1); timer.start(); } public void worktimeFunc(){ typeSet.setText("WorkOut"); roundCount = roundCount + 1; roundV.setText(String.format("%02d",roundCount) + "/" + String.format("%02d",round)); timer = new CounterClass(workTimeInMillis,1000,2); timer.start(); } public void resttimeFunc(){ typeSet.setText("Rest"); timer = new CounterClass(restTimeInMillis,1000,3); timer.start(); } public void cooldowntimeFunc(){ typeSet.setText("Cool Down"); timer = new CounterClass(coolDownTimeInMillis,1000,4); timer.start(); } public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer { long millis; int methodNum; public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval,int methodNum1) { super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval); this.millis = millisInFuture; this.methodNum = methodNum1; } @Override public void onFinish() { timer.cancel(); typeV.setText("00:00"); if (methodNum== 1) { worktimeFunc(); } if (methodNum == 2){ resttimeFunc(); } if (methodNum == 3){ if (roundCount < round){ worktimeFunc(); }else { cooldowntimeFunc(); } } } @SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { millis = millisUntilFinished; pausemillis = millis; pauseMethodNum = methodNum; System.out.println(millis); typeV.setText(String.format("%02d",millis/1000)); } } public class CounterClass1 extends CountDownTimer { long millisTotal; public CounterClass1(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) { super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval); this.millisTotal = millisInFuture; } @Override public void onFinish() { timer1.cancel(); timer.cancel(); typeV.setText("00:00"); totalTimeV.setText("00:00"); } @SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { millisTotal = millisUntilFinished; System.out.println(millisTotal); pauseTotalMillis = millisTotal; int min = (int) (millisTotal/(1000 * 60)); int sec = (int) ((millisTotal/1000)%60); totalTimeV.setText(String.format("%02d",min) + ":" + String.format("%02d",sec)); } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Java timer in android. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) is the link.